# Solving recurrence equation by substituion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, recurrence

I am trying to solve `T(n) = sqrt(n)*T(sqrt(n))+sqrt(n)` by drawing a reccurence tree and solving it be the substitution method. But I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how the sqrt method will affect this process and I am looking for some pointers if possible

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `m=sqrt(n)` substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `T(n) = sqrt(n)⋅T(sqrt(n)) + sqrt(n)` as

```
T(n) = n1/2 + n3/4 + n7/8 + ...
```

We know `Σi=1,...,∞ 2-i = 1`, so you can say

```
T(n) = n1/2 + n3/4 + n7/8 + ... < n + n + n + ...
```

Now you only have to compute the length of the sum by solving `n2-x < 2` and you get something like `x ≈ log log n`.

So the solution is `T(n) = O(n ⋅ log log n)`.

Sorry, you was looking for a solution using the substitun method. I never done this so I read a discription on [this site](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec19.htm).

Let `T(sqrt(n)) = k ⋅ sqrt(n) ⋅ log log sqrt(n) + O(sqrt(n))` for constant `k`.

```
T(n) = sqrt(n) ⋅ k ⋅ sqrt(n) ⋅ log log sqrt(n) + sqrt(n) + O(sqrt(n)) 
     = k ⋅ n ⋅ log (0.5 log n) + sqrt(n) + O(sqrt(n))
     = k ⋅ n ⋅ log log n + log 0.5 + sqrt(n) + O(sqrt(n))
     = k ⋅ n ⋅ log log n + O(sqrt(n))
     = O(n log log n)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: but i need to use the substitution method

Comment: oh, sorry, I didnt see this.